# How to get age from this form group's function in Angular and store it on back-end?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I've found interesting function here from another post which checks if the person is 18 years or older or not. I want to get age converted and set in the back-end separately but the point is that I don't have age input in HTML. Here is the code:

```
    this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
            'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required
            ]),
           'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
           'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)
            ]),
             'day': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2),
             ]),
             'month': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)
             ]),
             'year': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.minLength(4)
             ]),
         });
         this.SignupForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
       }
          private minimumAge(age: number): ValidatorFn {
            return (fg: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
              let result: ValidationErrors = null;
              if (fg.get('year').valid && fg.get('month').valid && fg.get('day').valid) {
                // carefull, moment months range is from 0 to 11
                const value: { year: string, month: string, day: string } = fg.value;
                const date = moment({ year: +value.year, month: (+value.month) - 1, day: +value.day }).startOf('day');
                if (date.isValid()) {
                  // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
                  const now = moment().startOf('day');
                  const yearsDiff = date.diff(now, 'years');
                  if (yearsDiff > -age) {
                    result = {
                      'minimumAge': {
                        'requiredAge': age,
                        'actualAge': yearsDiff
                      }
                    };
                  }
                }
              }
              return result;
            }
          }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.SignupForm.statusChanges.subscribe(res => if(status == 'VALID'){
    let day = this.SignupForm.get('day').value;
    let month = this.SignupForm.get('month').value;
    let year = this.SignupForm.get('year').value;
    let age = (new Date().getYear()-new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0).getYear());
}
}

    signupUser() {
      this.authService.registerUser(this.SignupForm.value).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.tokenService.SetToken(data.token);
          this.SignupForm.reset();
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['posts']);
          }, 3000);
        },
        err => {
          if (err.error.msg) {
            this.errorMessage = err.error.msg[0].message;
          }

          if (err.error.message) {
            this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

How can I get converted age value from this typescript function and send it to the database without using age input in HTML?

Comment: It does feels like you simply want to calculate someone's age based on day, month and year that user passes from the form inputs. But you found `minimumAge(number)` function from another post and want to use it to calculate age. You don't need all of `minimumAge(number)` function to do that. That function there is used for form validation. You can create a much simpler function by deleting unnecessary code from that function or create new one as suggested by @Vinko in his answer.

Comment: @Mausam can you show it on an example? I need validation for 18 and older that is why I kept above function and at the same time want to send converted valid age in the backend without HTML input.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda simple, if you have Date Objects. I'm providing you with single line of code that will do the magic.

```
console.log(new Date().getYear()-new Date(1995,12,17,0,0,0).getYear())
```

EDIT:

I'm gonna recreate it for you:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm.statusChanges.subscribe(res => if(status == 'VALID'){
    let day = this.signUpForm.get('day').value;
    let month = this.signUpForm.get('month').value;
    let year = this.signUpForm.get('year').value;
    let differenceInYear = (new Date().getYear()-new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0).getYear());
}
}
```

with variable differenceInYear you can do whatever you want with your logic

Comment: Thanks for replying. But have you checked my example code? It seems something different than your answer.

Comment: well you have fg.value. from that you can create new Date object and get difference?

Comment: It checks if user 18 years old or older. But besides that, I want to get converted age and send it to the backend without user input in HTML. I also assume it's my mistake I should change fg into SignupForm

Comment: I assume should add something in SignupForm but don't know what exactly?

Comment: I've edited code in my question and implemented yours. Should it look like that? I am asking it because it shows red lines under all your code lines.

Comment: ngOnInit is lifecycle hook and has to be implemented inside of component. Also, you have to check that there is only one instance of OnInit method inside of your component.

Comment: It says expected 0-3 arguments but got 5 under all lines of that block. In terms of Oninit it's in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you said you want validation plus the age. To do that whilst using your own code, I would first create a variable that holds the date in that component.

```
export class YourSignupComponent implements OnInit {
 age: number
 // ..rest of the code
```

Assuming the function works as expected I would then assign the age variable here:

```
if (yearsDiff > -age) {
// assign the new variable here
 age = yearsDiff;
 result = {
  'minimumAge': {
   'requiredAge': age,
   'actualAge': yearsDiff
  // ..rest of the code
```

The idea is that `age` variable will remain null if somebody is underage since form cannot be submitted without passing validation. But it will hold correct age if everything is good. Now you can grab this `age` variable as shown below and submit to backend.

```
signupUser() {
/* by the time this is executed, we will already have a valid form,
 so assign the variable to the form below and pass it to backend */
 this.SignupForm.age = age;
 this.authService.registerUser(this.SignupForm.value).subscribe(
  data => {
   this.tokenService.SetToken(data.token);
   // ..rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. If I got right this.SignupForm.age = age; sends all form details which was in the form group and also age with it. Great.

Comment: Yes it adds as an extra property to the form. A good way to ensure that is to check it by logging as `console.log(this.SignupForm);`. Add this after `this.SignupForm.age = age;` and check if all the values are about to be passed on as expected to the backend.

Comment: it says age property does not exist in FormGroup

Comment: One easy way to get around that is to create a new object based on form values and include age as property for that object. So instead of `this.SignupForm.age = age;` you can create a new object as `let objectToSubmit = {
      username: this.SignupForm.value.username,
      email: this.SignupForm.value.email,
      password: this.SignupForm.value.password,
      age: age,
      // rest of code,
    };
this.authService.registerUser(objectToSubmit).subscribe(
  data => {
  // rest of the code`

Comment: Anyway, the issue is there but this time besides age also under let :D